# How to align segmented buttons in extjs?

Tags: button, extjs

How can I align child buttons of segmented button in tabular layout? For example, if there are six buttons, how to arrange them in two rows with three buttons in each row?

```
Ext.create('Ext.button.Segmented', {            
     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
     allowMultiple: false,
     items: [{
          text: 'Segment Item 1',
     },{
          text: 'Segment Item 2',
     },{
          text: 'Segment Item 3'
     },{
          text: 'Segment Item 4',
     },{
          text: 'Segment Item 5',
     },{
          text: 'Segment Item 6'
     }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found it. If someone needs it, it is:

```
            layout: {
                type: 'table',
                columns: 3
            },
```